# How to count the frequency of a value in a column?

Tags: r

I would like to count how much each value appears in a column. The values that can occur in that column range from 1 to 15 so I would like the code to return a vector of 15 values with 0 if the value does not occur in the column and for instance 5 if the value does occur. Since I have to run the code a lot of times I didn't want to use a for loop looking at every single value and counting it, so I used the function table(). Right now I tried this:

```
N_k = rep(0,K) #make a zero vector for the number of people in a cluster
  table = as.data.frame(table(c(2,1,1,6,2,12,15,2,3,3,4,5,8,2))) #count number of people per cluster
  for (z in unique(table[,1])) {N_k[z] = table[table[,1]==z,2]}
```

However for some reason it returns:

```
> N_k
                                              1  2  3  4  5  6  8 12 15 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  4  2  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

I would like it to return:

```
> N_k
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15                     
 2  4  2  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1
```

Comment: Hi, please try this  ```table <-data.frame(table(aggregated_SleepActivity$cluster))``` or please share some sample data

Comment: Do you need `sapply(aggregated_SleepActivity, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = 1:!5)))` ?

Comment: I edited my code with how the vector could look like. When I used data.frame it still gave the same output...

Comment: hi,please elaborate more will be helpful to help.Like:- ```head(yourdf)```

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure I follow. I don't see how i could elaborate more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really just want a vector with the counts, you could do this:

```
# make a toy vector that matches the desired results you posted
z <- c(rep(1,2), rep(2,4), rep(3,2), 4, 5, 6, 8, 12, 15)

# run sapply over a complete sequence of integers up to the max in your vector
sapply(seq(max(z)), function(x) sum(z == x))
```

Result:

```
 [1] 2 4 2 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

If you want names attached to that vector, you could run `names(vector) <- seq(max(z))`. That gives you...

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
 2  4  2  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1
```